# Output all files inside Sub Folder: Absolute File Path

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am attempting to list the absolute path of all files inside a sub directory. I am able to find and output all files in that sub directory but the file path that I output is incorrect, ie one folder is missing.

My folder structure:

```
root:
    myBatchFile.bat
    SearchFolder:
        testfile1.txt
        testfile1.txt
```

When I output the file paths for all the files inside the folder 'SearchFolder' they are missing the SearchFolder.

Batch File Output:

```
C:/user/me/root/testfile1.txt
C:/user/me/root/testfile2.txt
```

The output should be:

```
C:/user/me/root/SearchFolder/testfile1.txt
C:/user/me/root/SearchFolder/testfile2.txt
```

**How can I make my Batch file code output the absolute path of the files inside 'SearchFolder'?**

```
REM // For all files in the folder 'SearchFolder': Compile them
for /r %%i in ("SearchFolder/*.txt") do echo %%i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
REM // For all files in the folder 'SearchFolder': Compile them
for /r ./SearchFolder %%i in ("*.txt") do echo %%i
```

Comment: wont that search in all sub directories inside 'root' and not just in 'SearchFolder'?

Comment: Yes it would. Is the directory that you need to search in going to be the same at all times ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. This would only search the specific SearchFolder directory.

Answer (score 0):

This will do for a single folder.  Reduce %%a to %a for a command line version.

```
for %%a in ("d:\abc\*.txt") do echo "%%a"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REM // For all files in the folder 'SearchFolder': Compile them
for %%i in ("SearchFolder/*.txt") do echo %%~Fi
```